# Access: merge 2 tables, based on the name of table 1 and a column in table 2

Tags: database, ms-access

I have microsoft access 2007 database, and I want to write a query to merge 2 tables in this database.

Table 1:

```
ID       color
1        red
2        orange
3        green
4        blue
5        purple
6        yellow
```

Table 2:

```
Name        Value
Table 1        27
Table 2        31
Table 3        65
```

The result should be
Table 3:

```
ID       color       Value
1        red           27
2        orange        27
3        green         27
4        blue          27
5        purple        27
6        yellow        27
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility, others include sub queries, but i suspect you have oversimplified, because if you really wanted to update every record to a single value, you would do just that.

```
  UPDATE Table1, Table2 
  SET Table1.Value = Table2.Value 
  WHERE Table2.Name = "Table 1"
```

I hope that Name and Value are due to simplification, and are not real names.